# Allow decimal/period to input field allowed characters

Tags: jquery, html

I have disabled the use of any other characters apart from text in an input field but I need to also allow the decimal/period character too but I am not sure where to begin...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.surnameInput').keypress(function(key) {
                if((key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 122) && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 90) && (key.charCode != 45)) return false;
            });

        });

    </script>



<form action="#">
<input type="text" id="surname" class="surnameInput" />
</form>
```

Her is a demonstration of this live:

https://jsfiddle.net/r31g6rqk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.surnameInput').keypress(function(key) {
    if((key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 122) && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 90) && (key.charCode != 45) && (key.charCode != 46) && (key.charCode != 44)){
          return false;
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="surname" class="surnameInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use it's ascii code `44`and `46`:
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r31g6rqk/1/)

Comment: I am ever so sorry to ask but is there a way to add numerics too as well as text and the period?

Comment: Same, add their ascii value range

Answer (score 1):

The period code is 46, so you could change your if to something like:

`if((key.charCode !== 46) && (key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 122) && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 90) && (key.charCode != 45)) return false;`

Comment: I have also just realised I may need numerics in there too...Sorry I know I didnt ask that but is there a way to allow numeric characters too?

Comment: so you need numerics and periods only?

Comment: numerics, text and periods only, I am ever so sorry

Comment: is it an option to use regex then? I feel like that if is getting too messy